# How to reuse existing vanilla js d3 visualization with angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to link one of the existing d3 charts written in d3.js with angular 5.

I tried saving the D3 code in a file **visualization.js** and imported the same inside component.ts file as **import * as vis from './visualization.js'**; and facing **error TS2306: visualization.js is not a module**.

Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Note: I don't want to wrap the d3.js inside a typescript class, this helps me to integrate several other d3.js charts easily without touching their source code.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the problem using the following approach.

1) save the d3 code into visualization.js and export main function which triggers the graph creation - **module.exports = function drawGraph(svgEl, width, height){ //code for visulization }**

2) import js function into graphWrapper.component.ts file -  **import * as drawGraph from './visualization.js';**

3) graphWrapper.component.ts overall:

```
import * as drawGraph from './temp.js';

// Exports the visualization module
export class BubblesChart {
    target: HTMLElement;
    height: number;
    width: number;
    constructor(target: HTMLElement) {
        this.target = target;
        this.height = 600; //Number(target.getAttribute('height'));//300;
        this.width = 1200; //Number(target.getAttribute('width'));//900;
    }

    render(values: number[]) {
        drawGraph(this.target, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

4) import graphWrapper.component.ts into any component directive and invoke render function.

Note: component.css styles will not be applied, have to use global styles.css or link external css file to angular-cli.json

Refer to following link for more explanation:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-custom-vizualizations-angular-d3-trs/index.html#N10118